# How do I increase all sides of an area created with extrude along normals

Tags: edit-mode

I want to create an object which basically is a cube on to top of another (rectangular) cube (to copy an object - see below).
I know that I could simply create two meshes and join them but I was sure it could also be done by starting with one mesh and extruding the top face along normals and then increasing side facing faces to be wider and deeper.
I created the rectangular shaped mesh and then used extrude along normals vertically which creates the 'top' which I want to increase its width and depth (X and Y).
I have tried selecting faces and then Scale and also G (drag) and extrude and I cannot get it to increase the faces along the X and Y axis.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Select the top face and hit <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd> (without <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> in between). Scale it as you wish then hit <kbd>E</kbd> again and drag upwards. You can then select the front and rear faces of the top box and scale them on the <kbd>X</kbd> axis to increase the width.

[image]

Comment: I didn't know you don't have to right-click for 0-displace extrude, nice

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Really? I've been using that method for years! :^)

Comment: Thanks John.  I should really have thought about working on the top face first and the extruding upwards to create my larger 'box' on top of the 'post' (instead of creating the top 'box' and then trying to enlarge it on the X and Y axis.

Comment: Well you could have done it that way! Just select the ring of faces round the pillar using Alt-Click on one of the edges then use Alt-E > Extrude Faces along Normals, but my way creates cleaner topology.

Comment: Thanks John.  I felt that it should have been possible the way you explained above but either didn't know or had forgotten about using Alt-E

Comment: I used both methods and prefer your first method (which you also do). It creates a few less edges.